# Making a custom drill bit out of steel epoxy putty?

Tags: metal, epoxy

I have a unique situation that calls for a custom drill bit which I decided to make out of JB Weld Steel Stick, a metal epoxy putty. I am curious whether this is an appropriate use of the material since I found specs about its tensile strength but nothing about its torsion strength. I did a small test where I used a wrench to twist a shaft moulded out of the steel stick and it appeared to break with little force. The area where it broke almost seems to crumble.

It appears to be good at resisting compression forces but not so good with twisting ones. Is there a better alternative or should I become a blacksmith?

[image]

---

UPDATE

For some background, I am trying to create a bit whose female end fits the square shaped dough roller attachment and male end is a standard hexoganal drill bit attachment.

[image]

Comment: Instead of trying to make one, maybe show us what you need and someone here might know of one already made.  Making a bit that will last not easy.  Shape is easy but the hardness and sharpness are two different things.

Comment: You didn't reinforce it with metal shavings?

Comment: What are you intending to cut with it? Soap, with a [brace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brace_(tool))?

Comment: I cut teeth into a steel pipe with a hacksaw - drilled through a brick eventually... Describe what you want to do.

Comment: I updated my post. I don't intend to cut anything with the bit, just use it as an adapter for a dough roller since I don't have a kitchenaid machine

Comment: Epoxy, of any kind, is a type of plastic resin. Coloring it gray with metal dust does not make it appreciably stronger, and does not make it a suitable material to make tools out of.

Comment: What are you going to use to *drive* the dough roller?  A Kitchenaid's output on "fast" still goes rotates a lot slower than any drill I've ever owned.  If you—through some magic—have a drill that will go slow enough, you can use a 1/2" adapter like this: https://www.harborfreight.com/impact-rated-hex-shank-socket-driver-set-3-pack-64604.html with a 1/2" double female adapter like this: https://www.amazon.com/Sunex-216fp-2-Inch-Female-Socket/dp/B006L23ILO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want 8 point sockets. You can adapt the standard square drive (3/8" or 1/2" or whatever) to get hex for your drill.

You can buy individual sockets from Amazon or McMaster Carr if you have trouble locally sourcing single sockets.

Comment: 11.5 mm across flats seems like a tricky size to find.

Comment: @jasen, try 7/16".

Comment: And a few beer can shims if needed for a perfect fit.

Comment: calipers say it's bigger than 7/16

Comment: @Jasen, I see some twist in the square edge relative to the caliper edge. I suspect that it's actually 7/16".

Comment: thank you this is what I plan to use. I had one of these lying around but never thought it could fit square sockets. Sure beats the universal socket wrench I was using before.

Answer (score 3):

Just as an alternative - I'd at least see if a regular 1/2" square socket extension would fit. The other end will just clamp in your drill. It is unlikely to really matter if it's a tad loose, you're not building aircraft ;)

[image]

For some reason I just expect everyone already has a set of sockets & would have tried the 11mm [or 7/16 in old money] already.

Comment: For a square drive you'd need an 8- or 12- point socket. While readily available, most socket sets are 6-point. But you could always check the fit with a common 12-point ring spanner before buying a socket.

Comment: @ChrisH - the idea was just to see if the square drive itself would fit, without a socket.

Comment: my comment relates to your last paragraph

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could get the torsional strength, you wouldn't get adequate centration by forming putty. So the drill would move around if the head was fixed, or vice versa. If you tried to fix them together, something would break.

If you were going to use epoxy in this job, using it as a filler for a slightly oversize socket would be better as there would be far less margin to be off-centre.

And if you did want to cast a custom part out of resin, it would be stronger to use a  steel bolt as the shank that goes into the drill. Then cast your adaptor around the bolt head, possibly backed up with a (wing) nut hard up against it.